# Propagating uncertainty in a Markov chain with absorbing states

Tags: confidence-interval, markov-chain-montecarlo, markov-process, uncertainty

Consider a Markov model with two absorbing states $a$ and $e$ and three transient states, with an associated transition probability matrix like so:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ p_{ba} & p_{bb} & p_{bc} &0 & 0 \\ 0 & p_{cb} & p_{cc} & p_{cd} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & p_{dc} & p_{dd} & p_{de} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Absorbing probabilities for states $a$ and $e$ are straightforward to calculate, but how do we propagate uncertainty around transition probability estimates? If for each $p_{ij} \neq 0$ & $p_{ij} \neq 1$ entry we had the estimate and 95% confidence interval, how would we propagate this out? Each row should sum to 1, and this can go askew if we're considering the envelope of uncertainty.

I'm wondering if a bootstrap style method to deal with this is the best thing to do. For example, if $p_{ba}$ was 0.4 with 95% CI of 0.38-0.42 while $p_{bb}$ was 0.35 (0.95% CI 0.33-0.37) and $p_{bc}$ was 0.25 (0.95% CI 0.23-0.27) etc would you pick a discrete step (say 0.01) and find all possible configurations of these values that sum to unity, and then propagate them out, finding the mean value of this vector and 95% CI from this, or is there a more conventional approach to dealing with this?